# how to change value return by _stock_status

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-status, meta-value

i am finding how to change the value from _stock_status on single product. I have display the product stock status by that code:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock_status', true ); ?>
```

but '_stock_status' return the value: "outofstock". I want to change this value to other name

Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code `update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock_status',$value)` to change the value of the meta. Please place the above line in the code where you want to change the status value and remember $value is the variable/array/object you can place any string/array/object in it.